# How long do vitamins last in multivitamin juice?

Tags: refrigerator, juice, vitamins

I like to drink multivitamin juice similar to [this](http://www.sainsburys.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/gb/groceries/tropicana-multivitamins-juice-juice-850ml), but it takes me a 3 or 4 days to drink whole carton.

How long will these added **vitamins** last, when kept in the refrigerator?

How long will they last, when I keep the juice in a room temperature?

I'm not asking how long the juice will be safe to drink, but only about the vitamin content (A, C, and various from the B group).

Answer (score 2):

If you drink up your juice within 3 to 4 days, the vitamin content will not decrease significantly. Usually, if properly stored, vitamis last for years.

Here is a link to some more information. Although not specifically talking about juice, I still found it informative: https://labdoor.com/article/do-vitamins-go-bad

Answer (score 0):

Vitamin and general nutritional content are consumed by "living" food

Once the food has been processed or preserved the nutritional content should be in a static form till the date provided by the manufacturer

Bottled juice has usually been pasteurised and all yeast and bacterial action and therefore nutritional change should have ceased if stored as recommended before opening, and after opening

Comment: "are consumed by living food" - not only. It's true that a picked fruit is still alive in the sense that it has a metabolism and can use up its own vitamins. But vitamins etc. are large molecules with a complex structure. They tend to break up over time due to simple entropy, not because they're used up by a biological process. So it is safe to assume that the vitamin content of a pasteurized juice will decrease.