# Convert vitamin powder to something edible

Tags: vitamins

I would like to add a vitamin powder to some food I have but unfortunately the vitamin powder(I have read) degrades when I attempt to put in water for more then a couple days it looses its benefits [according to this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60261/how-long-do-vitamins-last-in-multivitamin-juice).  What options do I have to add the powder to some food I have such that it doesn't involve heat/water?  I can't simple sprinkle it on top because well it the food I am trying to add it to is round and isn't an ideal solution.  Think trying to add it to check mix.  I am trying to prepare the food in advance if that isn't clear.

Comment: Curious? Why can't you just pop a multi-vitamin pill instead of trying to over-complicate things ?

Comment: @Max I am actually mixing multiple vitamins/supplements under the advice of a nutritionist.  So the powder is exactly one type of powder and even comes out multicolored.

Comment: Your nutritionist should be the one telling you how to ingest the vitamins, no ? and I'm still confused that you cannot just have a multi-vitamin pill, those are stable and you can ingenst when/where ever you need to.

Comment: @Max I'll ask the nutritionist.  ahh so putting the powder in a empty capsule could work but I'm not the biggest fan of pills we not necessary.

Comment: Vitamins how? You mean the powder of vitamin pills? That's not how food industry add Vitamins. Vitamin pills are for the intended use: swallow them, not added to food.

Comment: @William So you are anti-pills, but not anti the contents of pills? Could you explain what the problem with a pill capsule is? Also 'the food you are trying to add the powder to is round', if a confusing statement. What *is* the food you are trying to add it to. Do you *only* want to add it to this one sound food?

Comment: @GdD so vitamins in addition to powder milk(not sure if this is technically a vitamin).  The literature seems pretty clear that powder milk should not be left in milk for more then a couple days(the minutes estimate isn't accurate after checking the time).  Either way it seems clear it isn't made to be prepared in advancae.

Comment: @Spagirl I'm trying to add it to check mix type snacks.  My point is that I can't simple sprinkle the powder on top.  I don't understand your last question.

Comment: @William I really think you need to step back and review your question. Include in the question, clearly, all this stuff about the origins of these powders, why you won’t take them as polls, what milk has to do with it, what the source of your current information is. But there is a strong chance that once you have explained clearly that we still may not be able to help.

Comment: The way I am interpreting this question is that you want a list of possible foods into which a water soluble powder can be mixed without dissolving. The problem is that we, as almsot all sites on the network, don't allow list questions. Yours is also complicated by having a criterion of "the vitamins shouldn't lose their power", which is a nutrition request and as such off topic, so we have to ignore it by definition. Basically, any questions which is roughly equivalent of "which food should I eat/make" are not accepted here.

Comment: @rumtscho This question is a combination of these 2 questions  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/60261 https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/60261/how-long-do-vitamins-last-in-multivitamin-juice You may choose to do what you want but I do believe consistency across the site is most important and is it stands my question simply lacks the specific powder and food I am trying to mix together hoping it would make it easier to answer(apparently it sounds like you deem it to broad).  I am not trying to ask which food to eat/make but do the exact same thing in the questions above.

Comment: Sorry, then I maybe don't understand your question? If you are expecting the answer to be of the form "mix it into X", where X is a food name, then it is not answerable because it would be too broad. If you are asking for the shelf life of your vitamins after having been mixed into water, then it is a duplicate of the question you posted (I only see one link) unless you mean some vitamin other than A, B or C. In that case, you should say which vitamins you mean, and edit the question so it can't be understood as asking which food to mix into.

Comment: @rumtscho added links to the question.  I'm not saying you made the wrong decision but to me it seems this is just a combination of 2 existing questions.

Comment: A discussion of why a question was closed should not be had within the question itself. The proper place for it is [meta]. I will roll back your edit, and you are welcome to open a meta question about whether it should be left closed or reopened, with links to the other questions there. This is the encouraged procedure when there is dispute about a specific question.

Comment: here are the links It is unclear why my specific question is unacceptable but these are.  Seems like mine just combines the following 2 questions.

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/60261
https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/27514/how-do-you-add-ingredients-to-fudge-without-stiring-it

Answer (score 2):

You could could mix it into softened butter (or a butter spread) and then top foods like toast or crackers with it.

Comment: I'm hopeful the powder isn't damaged by butter like it is by constant exposure to liquid.  Not a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

Treat yourself as if you were a young child, and pretend you're getting a 3-year-old version of yourself to take some medicine in powdered form :)

I personally like just putting it on a cold [sorbet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbet); we did this when our youngest could not stand the taste of an antibiotic, so we had to crush it in pill form and find ways to have her ingest it. Raspberry sorbet with sugar (and amoxicillin) on top did it.

You could also look at stabilizing it in some milk chocolate that melts at a relatively low temperature, but I don't know how you'd test the efficacy of the method, because I don't know how to measure vitamin strength after trying something like that.

But desserts are generally the best vessels in which one can sneak medications agreeably past even sensitive palates, so I'd go that route.

You could also try fruit - e.g. watermelon, just consume it immediately.

Comment: Just to clarify it isn't the taste that is the issue but the fact everything requires preparation almost directly before consumption or frankly isn't particularly stable to put in bag and consume later at your convince